# C++ Add string to existing text file

Tags: c++, text-files, memory-address

The code below makes a text file titled with the date and writes what was inputted on the command prompt onto the .txt. The problem is, Once I run the code a second time, it erases what was previously written and writes the newly inputted. If the text file already exists, I want to keep what was previously written, jump down two lines and add the new material. Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

void main()
{
    time_t now = time(0);
    tm *ltm = localtime(&now);
    int day = ltm->tm_mday;
    int month = 1 + ltm->tm_mon;
    int year = 1900 + ltm->tm_year;
    std::string d = std::to_string(day);
    std::string m = std::to_string(month);
    std::string y = std::to_string(year);
    std::string info;
    std::getline (std::cin, info); 
    std::ofstream notes(m + d + y + ".txt", std::ios::out);
    if (notes.is_open())
    {
        notes << info;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "couldn't make file";
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/

Comment: [`std::ios::app`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode)

Comment: Worked perfectly! Any idea how to remove the addresses that get written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your

```
std::ofstream notes(m + d + y + ".txt", std::ios::out);
```

For

```
std::ofstream notes(m + d + y + ".txt", std::ios::app);
```

This way you will append new lines at the end of the file

For more info on write modes: [Check this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/)